# Passing gpio interrupt to android application

Tags: android, user-interface, kernel, interrupt, gpio

I have an android 4.4.2 device which has a UART connector exposed for add-on modules. A GPIO is also part of this connector which can be optionally used by the add-on module to send signal to my android device. this interrupt will be processed by the android application.

Following are few ways I could achieve this with, but dont feel its the proper way to do though,

1. GPIO interrupt is conveyed to android app as input key using input_report_key()
2. Implemented poll() function for /sys/class/gpio/gpiox.

But none of the above seem to be the proper methods for me,
Can someone help me to know if there are any ways to convey the gpio interrupt to android application?

Comment: with the second method using poll(), I could notice that few of the interrupts being missed out.. is there any way that this can be overcome with?

Comment: I'd put a bounty for this question if I had more rep !

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all your inputs,

I was actually looking for the best way that I could convey the `kernel level` `GPIO interrupt` to the `android layer` (or an application).

I implemented in below manner,

- Exported the GPIO in kernel.
- Polling in the HAL.
- HAL Calls the framework's method (was registered in init)
- Framework's callback method broadcasts the intent to the end application.

Did not use the `second method` (input_report_key())as it utilizes the `input event framework` which i felt is not a proper way of doing.

Comment: I assume you are using poll() function for interrupt polling in HAL. But does your poll() exit on interrupt when phone goes to suspended mode?